# Битовые сдвиги и двухзначные числа

Tags: алгоритм, битовые-операции, int, деление, умножение

Это вопрос с квиза по джаве:

> Какой более экономичной для
> вычислительных ресурсов операцией можно
> заменить умножение или деление
> на натуральные двузначные числа?

*Правильный ответ* было угадать довольно просто (потому что речь про одно название, а действий два, причём противоположных):

> Битовые сдвиги

Но я не понимаю, как их использовать. Очевидно, что битовыми сдвигами можно делить и умножать на любые степени двойки. Но как что-то сделать с произвольными натуральными двузначными числами, я не понимаю.

Comment: С умножением на константу, понятно. Несколько сдвигов и сложений (вычитаний). С делением даже на константу, не очевидно (но компилятор легко справляется, заменяя деление умножением). Если оба сомножителя переменные, то imho дешевле аппаратно умножать (делить) (м.б. кроме случая степени двойки, которая обнаруживается парой операций)

Comment: @avp, вопрос в точности как был на квизе, ничего к его условиям я добавить не могу. В моём понимании двухзначный множитель - известная константа. Тем не менее, я не понимаю, как это применить. Вот пусть я хочу умножить на 10 - и что мне с этим делать? Умножить на 8, умножить на 2 и сложить? Но сложение вроде уже не битовый сдвиг - получается, одних сдвигов недостаточно? И как в этой схеме участвует двузначность числа?

Comment: Двузначные в десятичной системе?

Comment: Насчёт деления - для двузначных чисел можно составить таблицу, подобрав к каждому константу и битовый сдвиг такой, что `X / N = (X * C(N)) >> shift(N)` выполняется точно для всех нужных X. Это к тому, что двузначные - таблица маленькая.

Comment: @defaultlocale, а в какой надо? Вопрос скопирован полностью, никаких гарантированных уточнений по нему я дать не могу. Я рассматривал как дефаултную десятичную, да и не вижу причин считать, что в других будет лучше (по крайней мере кроме двоичной).

Comment: C умножением просто, а вот с делением... Разве что заменить деление умножением на подходящее значение?

Comment: @Harry, что именно просто? Как мне на 13 умножить используя только сдвиги?

Comment: Сдвиги и сложения. \*13 == \*(8+2+1) Совсем одним не получится, но из условия не следует, что нельзя использовать другие операции. Вам нужно заменить единственную операцию умножения, т.е. изъять из списка арифметических операций умножение и ввести иную. По крайней мере мне так кажется. Так сказать, *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух* :)

Comment: @Harry, только +4, а не +2 ;) И что-то у меня сомнения, что сложение 3 сдвигов будет быстрее умножения. И что при ответе "битовые сдвиги" вообще можно использовать сложение.

Comment: Тогда ой :) Разве что просто суммировать :) - опять же быстрое суммирование - х, потом х+х, потом 2х+2х, потом так же получить 8х, потом их просуммировать...

Comment: Но деление суммированием не заменяется прям вообще. К тому же, битовые сдвиги были озвучены как верный ответ)